# Not able to update Crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

Hi I'm using VS2010 and Crystal reports (SAP Crystal reprots, version for VS2010). When I modify anything in my rpt file it is not effecting in output.

Every time same report is loading. I think it is executing from temp location.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Never happened to me; anytime rpt is modified output is effected. Are you talking about data-query changes? Look at "Save data in the report" flag in preview. Post some code to get help!

Comment: No.. even though I've added some static text in report header or footer, it is not at all reflecting.